# How to draw |x-y| <= 1/2

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying different solution but unable to draw something like this.

[image]

Comment: I mean in Latex!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Since this is tagged `pgfplots` here is a way to create something of that sort with this package.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1.1,xmax=1.1,ymin=-1.1,ymax=1.1,
grid=both,minor tick num=4,xtick={-1,0,1},ytick={-1,0,1},axis lines=middle,
major grid style={thick}]
\addplot[color=purple,thick,name path=upper] {x+1/2};
\addplot[color=purple,thick,name path=lower] {x-1/2};
\addplot[purple,opacity=0.6] fill between [of=upper and lower];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]